Clockpunk horror movie involving zodiac based creatures
I watched this movie when I was 5 or 6 maybe so don't judge me much. The movie is horror, it is about damned people. One native American looking man wears a steel frame-box thing on his head, another one is a child on a scooter, one has horseshoe nails in his head and takes them out and uses them as projectiles.
The main protagonists (don't remember, I think one female, one male and a child?) move through a glass labyrinth, and then they write some thing on glasses. Then the nail guy hits male the protagonist in the shoulder or hand.
There is also one scene where these guys (monsters and protagonists) stand around a clock like mechanism and play some kind of "zodiac game" and the mechanism breaks and then everyone goes apeshit about it. Yeah, I think the monsters resemble zodiacs.
The second scene is the scooter guy is circling around some round room.

In which year you was at 5?

You are definitely looking for the horror movie Thir13en Ghosts from 2001.

Arthur and his two children, Kathy and Bobby, inherit his Uncle Cyrus's estate: a glass house that serves as a prison to 12 ghosts. When the family, accompanied by Bobby's Nanny and an attorney, enter the house they find themselves trapped inside an evil machine "designed by the devil and powered by the dead" to open the Eye of Hell. Aided by Dennis, a ghost hunter, and his rival Kalina, a ghost rights activist out to set the ghosts free, the group must do what they can to get out of the house alive.

The house is full of 13 specific ghosts, designed after some kind of "Black Zodiac":


The Hammer – [...] The townsfolk executed George by chaining him to a tree, driving railroad spikes into his body, severing one hand, and attaching the hammer to it. His ghost is still pierced with the spikes and wrapped in the chains, and he wears the hammer in place of his missing left hand.
The Jackal – [...] Ryan was then confined to a basement cell, with a metal cage locked around his head, and grew to hate all human contact. When a fire broke out, everyone but Ryan escaped; he chose to remain behind and let himself be burned to death. His ghost wears the loosened straitjacket and head cage, whose front bars have been snapped apart.


(I can't really make much of the "scooter guy", though. But there are two child ghosts, just none with a scooter or circling anyone, I think.)
The finale is around the heart of the house, which is a clockwork-like mechanism that is supposed to open said Eye of Hell and during the showdown the whole thing breaks to bits.

I agree with you that this sounds a lot like Thir13en Ghosts, but the scooter scenes don't ring a bell either, unless Bobby (the younger boy) has a scooter at some point...?
